# Absolute fastest way to recursively delete all files and folders in a given path. Linux

Tags: linux, perl, filesystems, delete-file, delete-directory

I am looking for the absolute fastest method of performing unlink and rmdir commands on a path containing millions of files and thousands of folders.

I have found following perl one-liner, but this does not recurse and also performs a stat before each unlink (this is unnecessary):

```
perl -e 'for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

Comment: `rm -rf <toplevel-foldername>`

Comment: It won't get much faster than `rm`

Comment: Using `rm` as Hunter shows would be the fastest, but if you want a more portable perl solution, then you could use the `remove_tree()` function from the [File::Path](http://search.cpan.org/~riche/File-Path-2.11/lib/File/Path.pm) module.

Comment: I am also looking for a recursive perl one-liner

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to make much difference either way - CPUs are fast, disks are slow. Most of the work - however you do it - will be the traverse and unlink system calls.

There's not really a way to speed that up (well, short of maybe just initialising/quickformatting your disk and starting over).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to delete all files and folders recursively that I was able to find is:

`perl -le 'use File::Find; find(sub{unlink if -f}, ".")' && rm -rf *`